# Only return eloquent result if eager loaded value has value?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

What I would like to do is get a list of all conversations that only have a latestMessage and return a JSON output.

A Conversation hasMany Messages, but only hasOne Latest message:

```
public function latestMessage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Message::class)->latest();
}
```

**User Modal**

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conversation','conversation_participants', 'user_id', 'conversation_id');
}
```

**ConversationsController**

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user_id = $user->id;

    $conversations = $user->conversations()->with(['latestMessage'

        //Gets conversations that aren't with the user signed in
        ,'participants' => function ($query) use ($user_id){
        $query->where('user_id', '!=' , $user_id);
    }])->orderBy('updated_at','desc')->take('20')->get();

    return $conversations;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
$conversations = $user->conversations()
    ->has('latestMessage') // <-- limits results to conversations with a latestMessage
    ->with(['latestMessage','participants' => function ($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('user_id', '!=' , $user_id);
    }])
    ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
    ->take('20')
    ->get();
```

Here is the relevant section of the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence